# How to extend class inside module.exports in node js?

Tags: node.js, class, module, extends, module.exports

So, using Node.js v18.3, I don't want to write new class every time in there:

```js
module.exports = {Class1, Class2, /*etc...*/};
```

That's why I using this way of doing it:

```js
module.exports = {
  ClassName: class ClassName {
    constructor(...args) {
      // properties...
    };
  },
};
```

But, when I try to extend the class:

```js
module.exports = {
  ClassName: class ClassName {
    constructor(...args) {
      // properties...
    };
  },

  AnotherClass: class AnotherClass extends ClassName {
    // it does not work, sadly...
  },
};
```

It gives this error:

```
  AnotherClass: class AnotherClass extends ClassName {
                                           ^

ReferenceError: ClassName is not defined
```

Tried to work around it with this.ClassName:

```
  AnotherClass: class AnotherClass extends this.ClassName {
    // does not work too...
  },
```

But it did not work either:

```
  AnotherClass: class AnotherClass extends this.ClassName {
                                                ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

First of all, why does it? Why does it not work in first time, without `this.`? 
Second, how do I fix this or is there any other way doing this, without manually putting all classes in object, as I showed at the beginning of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re doing a [class expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#class_expressions) rather than a class declaration, so at the time your code runs inside `module.exports` the classes are not defined yet, so cannot be extended from.

Instead of using a single `module.exports` you could use multiple `exports`, for example:

```js
exports.Class1 = class Class1 {
  /* … */
};

exports.Class2 = class Class2 extends exports.Class1 {
  /* … */
};
```

Comment: Appreciate your help, thank you!